# Ruby on Rails as_json include where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, include

[image]

My issue I am having is, i want to include all these models when I query my object and return it via my API, but the only issue, is I want to only include on_the_ways where the user_id is not equal to nil. If the user_id is equal to nil, i do not want to include these models

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be very convenient if you use [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).